# ctrl plus v is not Working on Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this code for two fields phone_mobile and phone_home field. This code is working fine on the Chrome browser but on the Safari browser when I press ctrl+v a paste button appears near the cursor. I want it should paste the value directly to these fields.

[image: Check ScreenShot]

```js
$('#phone_mobile, #phone_home').on('keydown', function(event) {
  // Check if the Ctrl key (or Command key on Mac) is pressed along with another key
  if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case 'a':
        // Perform action when Ctrl/Cmd + A is pressed
        $(this).select();
        break;
      case 'c':
        // Perform action when Ctrl/Cmd + C is pressed
        $(this).select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        break;
      case 'x':
        // Perform action when Ctrl/Cmd + X is pressed
        $(this).select();
        document.execCommand('cut');
        break;
      case 'v':
        // Perform action when Ctrl/Cmd + V is pressed
        $(this).select();
        var inputField = this;
        var value = $(inputField).val();
        var isContactFormat = /^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(value);
        if (!isContactFormat) {
          // Remove existing formatting
          var unformattedValue = value.replace(/[\(\)\s-]/g, '');
          $(inputField).val(unformattedValue);
        }
        navigator.clipboard.readText().then(function(pastedText) {
          // Apply formatting to the pasted text
          var formattedText = pastedText.replace(/[\(\)\s-]/g, '').replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
          // Manually set the pasted text to the input field
          $(inputField).val(formattedText);
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', error);
        });
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Cell: <input type="text" id="phone_mobile" value="" /><br/>
Home ph: <input type="text" id="phone_home" value="" />
```

Comment: No one have solution of my query

Comment: execCommand supported only by a few browsers. Can you make the snippet a [mcve] and explain what you expect? I cannot even see it working in Chrome on OSX. I suggest you format the phone numbers on blur instead of trying to catch the clipboard which you need permission to do

Comment: I want to directly paste into the phone field on Safari with this code when i press ctrl+v a paste button appears as you can see in ScreenShot

Comment: As I suggested, remove all your code since you have TWO things that are not necessarily supported by the browsers on various platforms. I understand you want to format the phone number after paste, then instead do that on input or on blur, that will work on all browsers

Comment: `navigator.clipboard.readText()`is not avaible for firefox. Only for extentions. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText